# Generative grammars and analytic grammars?

Tags: formal-languages, terminology, formal-grammars

1. What are [a generative grammar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generative_gramma) and [an analytic grammar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_grammar#Analytic_grammars)?
2. How are they different from [a formal grammar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_grammar#Formal_definition)?
3. Is the recursive definition of the language of [a  propositional calculus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Propositional_logic#Generic_description_of_a_propositional_calculus), [a first order logic system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-order_language#Formation_rules), or [the set of lambda expressions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda_calculus#Formal_definition) a generative or analytic grammar?

Comment: What have you researched yourself?

Answer (score 5):

Generative Grammars were proposed by Chomsky in the 1950's as a
possible base for a theory of syntax of Natural Languages. The issue
was, and still is, to provide a mathematical description of (some
aspects of) Natural Language, so as to address more formally (more
scientifically?) the analysis of natural language. Other approaches
have since been developed, though grammars remain often one basic
ingredient of the analysis.

Their mathematical description is given in the [Wikipedia article you
reference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_grammar#Formal_definition). You can see yourself that **Generative Grammars are Formal
Grammars**  in the
usual sense of formal language theory. Indeed the work of Chomsky was
part of the founding contributions to formal language theory.

*Analytic grammars* is mostly a pragmatic technological concept.

Generative grammars were created to describe the syntax of natural
language, and the idea is that sentences of the language are obtained
from the initial symbol by applying the rules.

**Syntax analysis** is the reverse problem: given a sentence of the
language, can one find the succession of rules that were applied, and
were in the string they were applied, in order to generate the sentence.

This problem is simple for type 3 grammars, which are the grammars of
regular sets, but they are too weak to describe large parts of natural
language.

Type 0 and type 1 grammars are technically difficult to handle, both
theoretically and pragmatically, and the most successful class of
generative grammars has been the type 2 grammars, which are the
context-free grammars, of which several variants (no longer strictly
context-free) were since developed, as they are more powerful while
preserving many of the interesting qualities of CF grammars.

Still, syntax analysis, also known as *parsing*, remained a somewhat
difficult task, even in the CF case, given the very limited power of
the computers of the times.

Hence, subclasses of the CF grammars, and some variants, were
identified, characterized by the fact that they had a corresponding
parsing technology that was considered more tractable.

Some people thought it useful to describe the language syntax
(especially natural and programming languages, not mathematical
languages afaik) directly with such specialized classes or variants of
CF languages, so as to directly address the parsing problem (actually,
I am not sure they all are context-free, or deeply analyzed regarding
their mathematical properties)

This was a very pragmatic approach, to meet the computational
constraints of the computers. These grammars were conceptualized as
*Analytic Grammars*, but this is more circumstancial technology than a
fundamental concept.

The role of formal grammars in syntax is definitional and
descriptive. It should be simple, expressive and perspicuous with
respect to semantic concepts and whatever is understood of the
language structure, and generally easy to understand for human
beings. The issue of mechanized processing by computers should be
separated.

In general, when formalizing concepts mathematically, one must choose
the form that is the most appropriate to understand the concepts and
to reason about them, and to serve as reference definition. The
description must be perspicuous, expressive and hopefully
intuitive. But it should avoid concerning itself with practical
computational issues. This typically what is attempted with
denotational semantics of programming languages.

Then there can be other descriptions that are intended to better meet
technological and computational need, including possibly current
hardware technology and limitations and algorithmic know-how, but may
not be very convenient for human understanding and mathematical
reasonning. These are to be seen as secondary definitions used by
specialists and implementors, but not to be seen by most users.

One of the roles of implementors is to use these technological
descriptions for whatever purpose, after proving that they are
equivalent to the better reference description.

To take an image, there is an abstract way to describe a car by its
functionality and security measures. Most people, including
legislators, need no more. Then there can be other ways of describing
them by describing their internal make, but that is only a concern for
car makers, and it is far from a convenient description or a car for
users and legislators. Actually they do not care, as long as the maker
can produce a correctness proof, i.e. can show that the car works
consistently with the definition used by drivers and legislators.

So-called "analytic grammars" are to be placed in this category: a
device for implementors of parsers (i.e., syntax analyzers) for
languages, not a concept for understanding languages. I guess **Analytic
grammars could be seen as formal grammars, or may be as automata in some
cases**, but they are used specifically for their algorithmic properties. But
they first have to be proved conformant (i.e. generating the same
language) to the more natural grammar actually used to define the
syntax. And the relation with semantics has also to conform with the
corresponding semantics for the natural defining grammar.

Actually, things may be a bit more subtle or intricate, but this is to
give an idea of the role of multiple definitions of the same language,
and to explain the purely technical purpose of so-called "analytic
grammars".

Definition of mathematical languages and formalism are always
generative grammars, usually context-free, as what is desired is
expressiveness, clarity and mathematical tractability.